# Google Sheets, AppScript: How to run custom function with parameters on edit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

On google sheets, I have a custom function which is using cell values as parameters and doing a calculation in app script. I want this function to run on everytime an edit happens in the sheet to get the latest values.

```
function buildProfit(uniqueId, transactionType) {
  if (transactionType == 'Sale') {
    return 0;
  }
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var buyPrice = 0;
  var totalPrice = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i][1] === uniqueId && rows[i][4] === "Sale") {
      totalPrice += rows[i][7];
    }
    if (rows[i][1] === uniqueId && rows[i][4] === "Buy") {
      buyPrice = rows[i][7];
    }
  }
  var profit = totalPrice - buyPrice;
  return profit > 0 ? profit : 0;
}
```

I am calling this function in the cell like this **=buildProfit($B3, $E3)**
I understand there's a function called onEdit() but I am confused, how do I pass it via the sheet so that the parameters are passed well.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to change it to an onEdit(e) simple trigger.  Unless the cells containing uniqueId or transactionType change the formula will not recalculate.

Comment: Are you especting that the instance of the function in the sheet will be run when the onEdit trigger occurs? Because that's not going to happen it will have to run as a standard function and you will have to supply the parameter from some othersource like PropertiesService or Spreadsheet Cells.

Comment: The custom function should update every time the cells it is using to calculate the return value get updated. You are getting that behavior?

Answer (score 1):

#### Running a function with parameters from onEdit trigger

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [uniqueId,transactionType] = sh.getRange("A1:A2").getValues().flat();//getting parameters from spread sheet or perhaps you may wish to take them from your current spreadsheet
  buildProfit(uniqueId, transactionType);
}
```

#### Writing the same thing to three cells and changing the display with formatting

```
function elfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const f = ["MM/dd/yyyy","dd/MM/yyyy","yyyy/MM/dd"]
  sh.getRangeList(["A1","A2","A3"]).getRanges().forEach((r,i) => r.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat(f[i]))
}
```

Sheet0!A1:A3

| A |
| --- |
| 03/20/2022 |
| 20/03/2022 |
| 2022/03/20 |

If you can't do this then perhaps you don't have a Date() object in there in the first place

Comment: Thanks. Will I be able to apply this to all rows dynamically? 
=buildProfit($B2, $E2) This is what I have applied to all the rows, and the B2, E2 get applied dynamically.

Comment: No.  I'm assuming that you wished to run it as a regular function.  You cannot use onEdit trigger in any way to trigger instances of cell/custom functions

Comment: Could you tell me how do I change the value of a cell? I wrote the code to calculate the sum. 
Now, all I need to find the row based on the value of a cell, and change the value of another cell in the row.

Comment: I'm not interested is answering such questions.  I'm here to answer scripting questions.  You write code, you post it and then you have and error or a problem in a particular line or section and you ask us a question.  If we can answer we will if we can't we pass.  If you want to change the value of a cell you use setValue() or setValues() or appendRow()  That's one question and one answer.  Thant's all you get

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

You would have to replace the formula with the following script.  When the onEdit(e) is triggered by a change in any cell the value will appear in the cell that previously contained the formula.

**Script**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    // in case you want to limit edits to only Sheet1
    if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1" ) {
      var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
      var uniqueId = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
      var transactionTyoe = sheet.getRange("E3").getValue();
      var profit = 0;
      if( transactionTyoe !== "Sale ") {
        var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        var buyPrice = 0;
        var totalPrice = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          if (rows[i][1] === uniqueId && rows[i][4] === "Sale") {
            totalPrice += rows[i][7];
          }
          if (rows[i][1] === uniqueId && rows[i][4] === "Buy") {
            buyPrice = rows[i][7];
          }
        }
        profit = totalPrice - buyPrice;
      }
      // XX99 is the cell that contains the formula
      sheet.getRange("XX99").setValue( profit > 0 ? profit : 0 );           
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: Is B3 and E3 dynamic? Will it apply to every row?

Comment: This is how I am applying to all the rows in the column. =buildProfit($B2, $E2)

Comment: No.  So this formula is in every row?  Which rows, and will it grow?

Comment: Yes, I applied it on every row.  I added a screenshot in the main post to show how its applied

Comment: Why do you need to recalculate everything when a cell is edited.  It seems that its only limited to what is in the row of the unique id and the buy/sell dropdown.  Any change in a row doesn't affect the other rows.

Comment: So for example, if I am buying 4 products in one order, I can sell them separately 4 times. I want to calculate the total selling price, and know the profit I made on the purchase.

Comment: I think your process is flawed.  You have rows, some with the same id, but some sell some buy. You sum up the results for each row with the id.  But where do you put the result.  The first row with the id, the second, the last?  Instead I would have a drop down of ids.  Pick it, sum the results and display on the line with the drop down.  Or a list of unique ids and use that for the results.  Below that a list of transactions with multiple rows of the some id, some buy some sell.